# WordPress slider url issue in a localhost

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, url, slider

I'm trying to implement photo slider in the wordpress in a local host machine according to the following code:

https://github.com/devfreelex/sliderdevmean
and the video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_nSPiKWWmhs

the issue is the following:

in the index page I have the html code:

```
<article class="slider_item active"  slider-bg="image/slider/slide1.jpg">
<div class="slider_content">
    <h1>The title</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, nemo voluptatum accusamus!</p>
</div>
```

and in the jQuery page I have the js code:

```
// DEFINE BACKGROUND DO SLIDE
(function($){
    $('.slider_item').each(function(){
        var sliderBg = $(this).attr('slider-bg');
        $(this).css({'background-image': 'url("http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/photographysite/"'+sliderBg+')'});
    });
}(jQuery));
```

The goal is to pass the url to CSS

```
    element.style { background-image: url('http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/photographysite/image/slider/slide1.jpg');
```

}

does not work the http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/photographysite/image/slider/slide1.jpg so how can i pass the url parameter with the image?

Comment: `/photographysite/"'+`  take out that double quote in there that will be in the url.  It should be moved to the end `')'` append

Comment: I dunno what sliderBg is.  If it's as it is in the question, then it's an incomplete url.  You literally just need to move that `"` to the correct place in the string concatenation.  `'url("http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/photographysite/'+sliderBg+'")'`

Comment: Hi Taplar

you mean this:

<article class="slider_item active"  slider-bg='http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/photographysite/image/slider/slide1.jpg'>

and then 

$(this).css({'background-image': 'url('+sliderBg+')'});

did not work either

Comment: If you are getting all your images from the same place, it may be easier to just set a variable as that destination.

Comment: @João no, I'm saying if you change the concatenation issue then you don't have to change anything else about the value on the element or whatever.  Right now you are constructing the url incorrectly as it will be built as `'url("http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/photographysite/"image/slider/slide1.jpg)'` .  You see why that concatenation is wrong?

Comment: Provided that the example worked, the first function in this link is the way it should be set out I believe?? https://github.com/devfreelex/sliderdevmean/blob/master/slider/js/slider.js

Comment: If the slider bg attribute contains the complete correct url, with `"` or `'` around it, then yeah that would work.  I'm just trying to make sure it's clear to the OP why the concatenation in the question wasn't valid.

Comment: How is your folder layout? Do you have the "image" and "slider" folder labelled correctly? Because in the slider link you provided, he is using the folder labelled "images" whereas you are using a folder labelled "image".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to replicate the error. There were a few things I did to correct the issue.

---

1) I loaded the `.css` and `.js` files through my `functions.php` file which will be included (or created) with every Wordpress theme. If you require help in doing so, please follow this [LINK](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NF6r3Ejpris).

---

2) Changed the coding in the `slider.js` to use my full local path. For example, mine was `http://localhost/sliderJSreplica.com/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen/`. So my entire code is:

```
(function($){
    $('.slider_item').each(function(){
        var sliderBg = $(this).attr('slider-bg');
        $(this).css({'background-image': 'url(http://localhost/sliderJSreplica.com/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen/'+sliderBg+')'});
    });
}(jQuery));
```

***Please take note of where my apostrophes are located as you may have placed them incorrectly.***

---

3) Made the HTML markup for the attribute `slider-bg` as `slider-bg="image/slider/slide1.jpg">` according to each slide.

---

I hope that this works for you! If not, I would love to help further by providing one-on-one support via TeamViewer.

Answer (score -1):

First off I think you may be having issues with using jQuery in Wordpress as I have before. Try adding this `variable` before the start of your `function` and replace all the `$` with `j`.

```
var j = jQuery.noConflict();
```

Secondly, please refer Wordpress questions to the [Wordpress Stack Exchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/). It will help you find an answer quicker.

Comment: He's using an IIFE, passing in jQuery and then using the parameter $.  No conflict should not be his issue.

Comment: I know that is true, and you are correct, however I did it the EXACT same way and had a similar issue. The only way it worked for me was to use a `noConflict` solution. It may not be the solution needed for his instance, but it is worth a go.

Comment: There is very limited difference between assigning jQuery to a different variable and using that variable, vs passing jQuery into an IIFE.  In one case you are creating the variable yourself and in the other you are using the function parameter naming to do it for you.  They are effectively the same.

Comment: I didn't think it would work when I first saw the solution either, but it did. May have been a clash with a plugin perhaps, but whatever the reason using IIFE just completely stopped working for me and `noConflict` was the only way that worked.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/gycqn6L8/1/  They are effectively the same.  Something else is going on that isn't reflected in the question if this solved the issue.

Comment: I believe `jQuery noConflict Mode` was the issue, however perhaps another plugin replaced the jQuery term as that was not working either. https://www.mojowill.com/developer/using-javascript-with-wordpress-correctly/

Comment: Dear team,

I downloaded it the zip 

https://github.com/devfreelex/sliderdevmean 
with the
<article class="slider_item active"  slider-bg="images/slide1.jpg">
and
$(this).css({'background-image': 'url('+sliderBg+')'});

and the concatenation it works 100% without any conflict issue

Comment: Did you end up resolving your issue @João?

Comment: Unfortunately not yet, I'm doing a lot of testing.

Comment: I will try to recreate the problem and see if I can find the solution. Do you have any other slider plugins installed?

Comment: Also could you do me a favour and email me a copy of your .html and .js markup? administrator@hosting-mate.com